# Android activity showing black screen while changing tab

Tags: android

When i change the tab, then tab child activity background becomes black screen. I am facing This problem  in note(Nexus 7 ) and tablet ( Smasung Galaxy Tab). Please share some idea to resolve it.
First I clicked on first tab. At that time the activity is loading fine. Then I went tab 2. Then again I clicked on the first tab. At this time the screen goes black. Basically the layout bg is not loading.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using same layout for both activities?

Comment: no different layouts I am using..

Answer (score 0):

I am setting the same background image in tab_host.XML which image I used in the other layout.

```
            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab1" />
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab2" />
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab3" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>


</LinearLayout>
```